# Error message on R : "data set 'X' has not been found" when trying to do topic modeling although I have already used that data for other techniques

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, topic-modeling, word-cloud, topicmodels

I am doing a lyrical analysis of Paramore's discography using data from GeniusAPI. I have done most my analysis after going through data wrangling. I was able to create word clouds and bar charts based on sentiment analysis for each album. But now I am trying to conduct a topic model for one of these albums (Riot). To do this you have to make sure your data is a document term matrix.

Just at the first step an error message comes up when trying to do start the topic model

data(riottoken)

Error message: data set 'riottoken' not found"

Although I have used 'riottoken' for word clouds and sentiment analysis.

I tried to turn 'riottoken' (my data) into a corpus and a document term matrix using different codes and failed at this too. I will leave two examples below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using ‘data(.)’ when you think the object is already in your workspace? Generally one would use ‘ls’.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a beginner at coding, so I am just following someone's r markdown for topic modeling. https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation

Comment: Can you share more of your R code? Do you load any packages before calling `data(riottoken)`?

Comment: Also, what do you see when you type `riottoken` within your R session?

Comment: i have quite a few packages loaded including tm, topic models, quanteda, tidy text. my data (riottoken is a tibble with 770 rows)

Comment: If `riottoken` is a tibble you created, there's no need to call `data(riottoken)`. The `data()` function is only for loading data from a package. It has nothing to do with your own data. If you are having other problems turning `riottoken` into a corpus, you should focus on that code instead.

Comment: okay thanks that makes sense, so how would I turn my tibble into a corpus? I have tried a few codes including this one but it is not working. the code->   corpus = corpus(VectorSource(RIOTtoken))